# How to modify values of a XML in J2ME?

Tags: xml, java-me

Suppose there is a `XML` in my `J2ME` application :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appli>
   <client id=134447>
      <name>Patrick</name>
      <email>patrick@mail.com</email>
   </client>
</appli>
```

How to modify from `J2ME` the node value "patrick@mail.com" for example ?

Comment: does your target device support [JSR 280: XML API for Java ME](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=280 "API specification page")? _This JSR is designed to provide a general purpose XML API..._

Comment: If I understand then : not all devices support XML ?

Comment: what XML lib are you using ??

Comment: Till now I am thinking of the approach of storing many data ; `Recordstore` takes much memory in device so I want to choose the option of working with XML. So I don't know which library and stuff to use !

Comment: right - not all devices support XML API specified by JSR 280

Answer (score 1):

For you XML sample you could write a class like:

```
    class Client {
        String id;
        String name;
        String email;
    }
```

And unmarshall your XML to it. I have shared a way of doing this with SAX from JSR 172 at http://smallandadaptive.blogspot.com.br/2010/11/xml-data-binding.html.

To marshall your class back to XML you can create a method like:

```
    String toXML() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        sb.append("<client id=\"").append(id).append("\">");
        sb.append("<name>").append(name).append("</name>");
        sb.append("<email>").append(email).append("</email>");
        sb.append("</client>");

        return sb.toString();
    }
```